# No module named auth.urls

Tags: python, django

Im trying to use Django Social auth for Google auth but get this following error,

```
No module named auth.urls
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuthBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.yahoo.YahooBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.browserid.BrowserIDBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.linkedin.LinkedinBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.disqus.DisqusBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.livejournal.LiveJournalBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.orkut.OrkutBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.foursquare.FoursquareBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.github.GithubBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.vk.VKOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.live.LiveBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.skyrock.SkyrockBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.yahoo.YahooOAuthBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.readability.ReadabilityBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.fedora.FedoraBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.OpenIDBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/login-form/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/logged-in/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login-error/'
```

urls.pu

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #(r'^$',main_page),
    url('',include('social.auth.urls'))
```

)

its actuall pointing to the urls.py

Comment: Did you add the social_auth in INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: yes, I did and ran the syncbd command which ended successfully

Comment: my bad..it worked...I gave social.auth instead of social_auth

Comment: Yes you are right. I gave the answer same thing.

Answer (score 1):

social_auth Application Setup:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social_auth'
)
```

Ok I figured out your problem, you are using like `social.auth.urls` but you should use `social_auth.urls`

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
    ...
)
```

Link http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html